# How to refresh data input on change in Angular ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: refresh

I have template use ng-multiselect-dropdown

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [settings]="ItemSettings">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

when I update listItems with new Item, I want to refresh `[data]` in this select. How can I do?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use?

Comment: Hi, i have used same ng-multiselect-dropdown & facing same problem, Did you get any solution / workaround by dynamically updating [data] ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is, we can use `setTimeout()` as to refresh dropdown data list

For example, below works for me

```
setTimeout(()=> { this.your_dropdownList = data; },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update `listItems` to be returned from a method instead of referencing the property directly, Angular will recognize the update and pass the new values correctly.